# Hibernate saving the data if not present in DB else updating it

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am relatively new to hibernate and looking for any mechanism where I insert new record only if the composite key is not present and else update it.

I tried with saveOrUpdate method but seems it only works for the objects in the session.
I want some mechanism which should query at database and if the data is present in the database already then update the record else insert it.

Thanks,

Amandeep

Comment: Do just that: query the database, and if the object is found, update it, otherwise, persist it. Hibernate won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the hibernate docs,saveOrUpdate() method should satisfy your requirement.[Hibernate Session doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object))

> void saveOrUpdate(Object object)
>                     throws HibernateException Either save(Object) or update(Object) the given instance, depending upon resolution of the
>   unsaved-value checks (see the manual for discussion of unsaved-value
>   checking). This operation cascades to associated instances if the
>   association is mapped with cascade="save-update".
>
> Parameters: object - a transient or detached instance containing new
>   or updated state

Posting a sample code for your reference:
In the below method a Stock object is newly inserted into the database.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockId(70);
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("TEST SAVE");

        StockRecord stockRecords = new StockRecord();
        stockyRecords.setDaily_record_id(80);
        stockRecords.setPriceOpen(new Float("1.2"));
        stockRecords.setPriceClose(new Float("1.1"));
        stockRecords.setPriceChange(new Float("10.0"));  

        stockRecords.setStock(stock);        
        stock.getStockRecords().add(stockRecords);

        session.save(stock);
        session.save(stockRecords);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

Then in another method you open a new Session and then try to insert or update a Stock object(StockId is the primary key,if you give the same id,it will update and if you give a new id,it will insert,here i have retained it as 70)

```
public static void testSaveOrUpdate(){      
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockId(70);
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("Test SaveOrUpdate");

        StockRecord stockRecords = new StockRecord();
        stockRecords.setDaily_record_id(90);
        stockRecords.setPriceOpen(new Float("1.3"));
        stockRecords.setPriceClose(new Float("1.1"));
        stockRecords.setPriceChange(new Float("10.0"));

        stockRecords.setStock(stock);        
        stock.getStockRecords().add(stockRecords);

        session.saveOrUpdate(stock);        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Just make sure that if you have a relationship to some other entity(in this case StockRecord) you give the appropriate CASCADE value.In this case,CascaseType is set to ALL.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stockId", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Set<StockRecord> stockRecords = 
                            new HashSet<StockRecord>(0);
```